# In PHP delete last folder in the path

Tags: php

I'm having the path like "**AAA/BBB/CCC/DDD/test**" in this path I want to delete the last folder "**/test**" using PHP. I have tried the below code.

**Code**

```
$dirname = 'AAA/BBB/CCC/DDD/test'
remove_directory();
function remove_directory() {
    rmdir($dirname)
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the variable to the function:

```
$dirname = 'AAA/BBB/CCC/DDD/test'
remove_directory($dirname);
function remove_directory($dirname) {
    rmdir($dirname)
}
```

Of course, if your function has only one single line, you can simply use the built-in PHP function instead of defining your own that does the same thing.

I strongly suggest you take a few minutes and read the [manual page on variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Answer (score 2):

Use `basename()` function: this will give you the required folder name.

```
$dirname = 'AAA/BBB/CCC/DDD/test';
function remove_directory($dirname) {
    $dirname = basename($dirname);
    rmdir($dirname);
}
remove_directory($dirname);
```

Comment: This would delete the `test` folder from the current directory and not from the path specified.

Answer (score 2):

What is the complete path? Since you don't start your path with for instance `C:\` on Windows or `/` on Linux you are trying to remove a directory relative to the current working directory. This probably does not evaluate to the directory you are trying to delete.

If you want to access your `$dirname` variable inside your function you will have to use the [global](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global) keyword. But better practice is to pass the directory as a variable to your function.

Also, as a matter of good practise, you should have the function implementation before trying to call it. Usually, it doesn't matter, but there are a few exceptions, particularly when the existence of a function is conditional on some other code being executed.

Comment: If this is a full path or relative path can be an implementation specific choice, you don't have to have a full path for this to work.  You can also define the function and call in any order you wish.

Comment: Mike, that is why I didn't say must but should since it's a good practice to follow. Usually, it doesn't matter, but there are a few exceptions, particularly when the existence of a function is conditional on some other code being executed.

Comment: Nigel: Yes, what I'm saying is that this might be unintentional for the OP hence the question about what the path he/she is trying to delete is.OP could have used a rellative path without understanding it.

Comment: But the answer misses the important part that the variable with the path is out of scope of the function.  The rest may be useful comments but does not provide a solution to OP's problem.

Comment: Nigel: I was just editing the answer to include information about the global keyword (which I initially missed) and then I saw this comment. Feels like this should have produced a very easy to understand error message though that OP should have been able to identify.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you have created a function `remove_directory()` without an argument. So the variable inside your function `$dirname` has no content since it is out of scope of where you originally defined it. Possible solutions would be to ditch the function and write this:

```
$dirname = 'AAA/BBB/CCC/DDD/test'¨
rmdir($dirname)
```

or to correct your mistake:

```
$dirname = 'AAA/BBB/CCC/DDD/test'
remove_directory($dirname);
function remove_directory($dirname) {
    rmdir($dirname)
}
```